# Kylin Cardinality Calculation

Tags: hive, cardinality, kylin

I have a Kylin Cube built on some data that is partitioned on date. Whenever a new date's data is added into hive, Kylin is not able to detect it. Is this normal behaviour?

Currently I am manually reloading the table in data-sources tab. This calls for a recalculation of cardinality. The data is too big and calculation of cardinality is taking so long.

Can anyone help me? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When some data is added into the hive external table, we must run :
 `MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;`

Kylin will then be able to read the new partitions.